# How do you re-open the active document after calling saveAndClose?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'd like to know how to re-open the **active** document after calling saveAndClose.

I have a Google Docs Add-on ([Magic Rainbow Unicorns](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/magic-rainbow-unicorns/ganidpeaoklofmlmmlamgngfgjopjido)) that changes the font colour of every selected character to a different colour of the rainbow. If the document is really long (e.g. 100 pages) then I see the following error:

> ScriptError: Too many changes applied before saving document. Please
>   save changes in smaller batches using Document.saveAndClose(), then
>   reopen the document with Document.openById().

As suggested on another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38786153/1912127), I have a counter and am doing a flush after 50000 changes.

```
      // save & flush changes
      if (rainbowIndex%50000 == 0) {
        DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().saveAndClose();
        // reopen the doc and refresh the selection
        selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
        elements = selection.getRangeElements();
      }
```

However this code doesn't work because whenever I try to modify an element I see the error `Document is closed, its contents cannot be updated.`

I can't use `DocumentApp.openById` as suggested by the error message because my add-on only has permission for the current doc (`@OnlyCurrentDoc`).

So what I'd like to know is: if it's possible to re-open the active document after closing it because I don't want to change the permissions on my add-on? If it is possible, which method should I call?

Comment: To be clear, if you are working with `var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();`, after calling `doc.saveAndClose();`, you get an error doing `doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();` to reopen it? What error do you get?

Comment: I'm guessing you can't use openById with @OnlyCurrentDoc

Comment: @tehhowch There's no error when I access the active document, the error comes later when I edit the selected elements `Exception: Document is closed, its contents cannot be updated.`

Comment: @e__n You definitely can't use `openById` with `@OnlyCurrentDoc`. My question is not about that - it's how to save and flush when you're only working with the active document.

Comment: @Dagmar Not sure... weird. Was not able to reproduce, the above code worked fine for me. Are you able to open the document again? In the original post you ask if it's possible to reopen the active document after closing, but in comments you say there's no error accessing the active document.

Comment: You can try to find something in the Google Issue Tracker. This is kinda what you'd like: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761692

Comment: A rather involved solution would create a trigger save the last processed index in the document cache when you are at the 50k changes and return. Thenext iteration proceeding by looking up the last index. Once all indices were processed the trigger is deleted

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I imagine this is an operation invoked by sidebar/menu UI, and the user probably expects to only to click once to complete the operation, not several times.

Comment: @tehhowch This would involve clicking once only but it would take a while with scheduling etc

Comment: @e__n The above code works, but when I try to edit the elements I get an error saying you can't modify a document that has been closed. I'm unable to open the document using openById because I'm only working with the current doc.

Comment: @tehhowch you are absolutely right. What I want to do is flush the document after changing the font colour of 50K characters. However I can't do openById because I don't have the correct permission

Comment: @RobinGertenbach not sure how a trigger could help. My add-on works on a button push and changes the font colour of the selected text a character at a time.

Comment: The button would launch a manager, the manager checks if there is a progress reference in the cache. The manager launches the modifier from the latest progress, otherwise the start. The modifier keeps track of the number of changes. Once it hits a limit it will log it in the cache and returns whether it hit the limit or not. The manager sets up a trigger to relaunch itself in a minute if the limit had been reached otherwise deletes all trigger references to itself and returns.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach Thanks but that sounds like something that will definitely break (when the trigger just randomly decides not to fire like Google Triggers are want to do) and is way too complicated to make it worth implementing

Comment: What line is throwing the error? I've tried `function myFunction() {
  var d1 = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  d1.getBody().getParagraphs()[0].setSpacingAfter(10)
  d1.saveAndClose()
  var d2 = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  d2.getBody().getParagraphs()[0].setSpacingBefore(30)
}` for testing and it worked.

Comment: @filipeglfw no error is being thrown

Comment: @Dagmar, what line is causing this error `Document is closed, its contents cannot be updated.`? Can you share a bigger portion of your code? (Deleted previous comment because had copied the wrong error message)

Comment: @filipeglfw thanks for your code snippet. I didn't look at it properly yesterday. I tested it today and it worked - even when I edited it to use a selection and elements. So I looked into my code further and found a bug. I have posted an answer with working code. So!! it does seem possible to re-open the active document, which is fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to filipeglfw who pointed out a snippet that worked for him, I found a bug in my code. I had refreshed the active document, the selection and the elements in the selection, but not the element I was currently working with.

The below shows a working code snippet:

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 *
 * The above comment directs Apps Script to limit the scope of file
 * access for this add-on. It specifies that this add-on will only
 * attempt to read or modify the files in which the add-on is used,
 * and not all of the user's files. The authorization request message
 * presented to users will reflect this limited scope.
 */

function test() {
  var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var selection = document.getSelection();
  if (selection) {
    var elements = selection.getRangeElements();
    // go through each selected item and change the font colour
    var rainbowIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      var element = elements[i].getElement();
      var elementText, startIndex, endIndex;
      if (elements[i].isPartial()) {
        // they selected only part of a paragraph
        elementText = element.asText();
        startIndex = elements[i].getStartOffset();
        endIndex = elements[i].getEndOffsetInclusive() + 1;
      } else {
        // they selected whole paragraph(s)
        elementText = element.editAsText();
        startIndex = 0;
        endIndex = selectedText.length;
      }
      for (var j=startIndex; j<endIndex; j++) {
        elementText.setForegroundColor(j, j, "#CCCCCC");
        rainbowIndex++;
        // save & flush changes
        if (rainbowIndex%5 == 0) {
          document.saveAndClose();
          // reopen the doc and refresh the selection
          var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
          selection = document.getSelection();
          elements = selection.getRangeElements();
          element = elements[i].getElement();
          elementText = element.asText();
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    // there was no selection
    throw 'Please select some text.';
  }
}
```

Note, I am using a low number (5) for the refresh counter, but I believe it should be about 50000.